# Javascript disable switches current tab functionality in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to accomplished this on browser?

Disable opening another web page 
or disable switch current tab functionality in browser 
when certain page (in this case my page) is still open?

I want to make a quiz in web, but i want to eliminated the posibility for user search on internet for the answer, but have no idea how to accomplished that.
plis give me a solution..
regards..

Comment: Impossible. You could however automatically fail the user on losing focus, but that's just plain annoying.

Comment: Take a look at the Lockdown Broswer. My university used it for exams and quizes.

Comment: thanks @DaveChen.. i'd like to try it.. even if that'd be annoying to the user..

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible, for (what I hope are) obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This not possible.

Even if it was possible in theory, how would you stop the user opening another browser (different brand to the current one)?

How would you stop the user from using their mobile phone to search the web?

If this quiz is being run in a controlled environment (like a classroom) you could run the web browser in some sort of kiosk mode with strict policy setup against opening other tabs etc. But if it is being run in a classroom, then you already have someone supervising anyway. Why bother then